# How to install pam_mount on RHEL 8?

Tags: pam, rhel8

I'm trying to install `pam_mount` on `RHEL8` but keep getting this:

```
rror:
 Problem: package pam_mount-2.16-10.el8.x86_64 requires hxtools, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides perl(encoding) needed by hxtools-20150304-10.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

`Perl` is indeed installed:

```
# perl -v

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 51 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

Any tips on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities here:

1. You have disabled the repository `rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms`. The dependencies you need are in this repo.
2. Alternately, your RHEL subscription is expired or not active. An active RHEL subscription is required to install packages.

Comment: Thanks! I had it unsubscribed after running some ansible tasks, and that's why it wasn't working.